# ADM 201 will expire if I miss one maintanence exam?

Tags: certificates

Will my adm 201 expire if I miss a single release exam that is winter 2019, till December I wrote all exams and it was just behind a single release exam till April and I never got a reminder mail for the expiry , can anyone answer please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certification maintenance requirements are [documented by Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Certification-Release-Maintenance-Schedule):

> Keep in mind: If you don’t complete your maintenance requirements by the completion due date, your credential(s) will expire.

The due date for Winter '19 was April 19, 2019.

The full [Expiration Policy, here,](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Information-about-Certification-Expiration) explains that

> If your certification is at risk of expiring, you will receive email notifications reminding you to complete your maintenance. However, you should not rely on these email notifications; it is your responsibility to complete your maintenance by the published due date.

The only people who can assist you with questions about your specific certification status are Trailhead support.

Comment: But earlier it was 3 exams right ?, you can do it by the year end , this time it was a surprise,

Comment: My point was the certification will expire only if you miss 3 release exams . This time it’s the first one itself has taken my certificates away

Comment: @MATHEWThomas I don't recall any change in the expiration schedule, but in any case it's not something I personally can help you with. Trailhead support are the only people you can talk to that have the ability to directly assist you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just submitted a case for the same ,